# Lenovo laptop battery only charges to 68.1% capacity?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a [Lenovo Z50-75](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g40_g50_z40_z50_ug_english.pdf?linkTrack=PSP:ProductInfo:UserGuide) which supports battery charge limiting. Before I installed Linux, I had my battery set in conservation mode. I don't know if that had any effect on the matter but my battery does not get a full capacity charge, which is great for battery life conservation, but I wonder if installing Linux by formatting after setting up battery conservation in Windows had any effect on this.

Comment: It probably had an effect because the Windows tool probably tweaked parameters directly in the battery.

Comment: if so it just solved the problem of like thousands of owners of lenovo laptops using linux.

Comment: Suggest you post a detailed answer on how to alter the settings for Lenovo laptop users including where to get the software tool and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation Mode of your [Lenovo Z50-75](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_50_series_hmm.pdf) is altered by a Lenovo system tool, as described [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/How-to-set-my-Z580-battery-settings-to-fully-charge/m-p/911419) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-enable-conservation-mode-in-the-energy/8754f571-3dbe-42f9-aca0-cab22e7bf565). I do not see any [System Tools from Lenovo for Linux](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-75/downloads?linkTrack=footer:Support_Downloads&searchLocation=PSPDoc_S), so either use the Windows tool in Windows, or contact [Lenovo Z-series Laptop Support](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-75/contactus?searchLocation=PSPDoc_S) for a solution.

Comment: my intention was to provide an answer for thousands of people in need of this solution :)

Comment: Suggest you post a detailed answer on how to alter the settings for Lenovo laptop users including where to get the software tool and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The Archlinux wiki pages suggest the following method, which works on my Lenovo Ideapad.

This keeps my battery charged up to approximately 60%:

```
# echo 1 >/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

This disables the battery conservation setting, allowing the battery to charge back up to 100%:

```
# echo 0 >/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

I would search the Archlinux wiki for similar information regarding your specific laptop.  And you could just boot up any modern live Linux distro from a USB drive and, without installing, try to adjust the settings.  Just remember to set the desired mode before exiting the live environment, because this setting does survive a reboot.  Not sure if Windows would then clobber the setting?